# Amazon AWS PHP and sendmail, emails not delivered

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, sendmail

We've just moved a client's webspace to an amazon EC2 instance with an elastic IP.

I'm quite out my depth here as i'm not too clued up with linux OS's

The site is transfered and all working currently under our test domain http://base5.eu

Everything's functioning as expected, except for a couple of forms used for sending emails, a standard contact form and a application form.

The php scripts are using sendmail to handle the sending of the emails.

Its important to note that the Instance is only providing the website, the actual mail accounts for the domain are all google mail accounts.

we have set up MX records pointing to googles mail servers for the domain.
The dns settings are with 1and1 and there is no option to add PTR records.

currently while testing the site on our test domain base5.eu.

it seems send mail is sending the mail but the mail never gets delivered.

when looking at the /var/mail/root the message is there with the following:

```
From MAILER-DAEMON@ip-172-31-14-25.eu-west-1.compute.internal  Sat Dec  5 13:42:34 2015
Return-Path: <MAILER-DAEMON@ip-172-31-14-25.eu-west-1.compute.internal>
Received: from localhost (localhost)
        by ip-172-31-14-25.eu-west-1.compute.internal (8.14.4/8.14.4) id tB5DgYhQ007848;
        Sat, 5 Dec 2015 13:42:34 GMT
Date: Sat, 5 Dec 2015 13:42:34 GMT
From: Mail Delivery Subsystem <MAILER-DAEMON@ip-172-31-14-25.eu-west-1.compute.internal>
Message-Id: <201512051342.tB5DgYhQ007848@ip-172-31-14-25.eu-west-1.compute.internal>
To: <apache@ip-172-31-14-25.eu-west-1.compute.internal>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
        boundary="tB5DgYhQ007848.1449322954/ip-172-31-14-25.eu-west-1.compute.internal"
Subject: Returned mail: see transcript for details
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated (failure)

This is a MIME-encapsulated message

--tB5DgYhQ007848.1449322954/ip-172-31-14-25.eu-west-1.compute.internal

The original message was received at Sat, 5 Dec 2015 13:42:33 GMT
from localhost [127.0.0.1]

   ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<dizzy@base5designs.co.uk>
    (reason: 554-kundenserver.de (mxeue104) Nemesis ESMTP Service not available)

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to mx00.1and1.co.uk.:
<<< 554-kundenserver.de (mxeue003) Nemesis ESMTP Service not available
<<< 554-No SMTP service
<<< 554-Bad DNS PTR resource record.
<<< 554 For explanation visit http://postmaster.1and1.com/en/error-messages?ip=52.19.134.10&c=rdns
... while talking to mx01.1and1.co.uk.:
<<< 554-kundenserver.de (mxeue104) Nemesis ESMTP Service not available
<<< 554-No SMTP service
<<< 554-Bad DNS PTR resource record.
<<< 554 For explanation visit http://postmaster.1and1.com/en/error-messages?ip=52.19.134.10&c=rdns
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable

--tB5DgYhQ007848.1449322954/ip-172-31-14-25.eu-west-1.compute.internal
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; ip-172-31-14-25.eu-west-1.compute.internal
Received-From-MTA: DNS; localhost
Arrival-Date: Sat, 5 Dec 2015 13:42:33 GMT

Final-Recipient: RFC822; dizzy@base5designs.co.uk
Action: failed
Status: 5.5.0
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 554-kundenserver.de (mxeue104) Nemesis ESMTP Service not available
Last-Attempt-Date: Sat, 5 Dec 2015 13:42:34 GMT

--tB5DgYhQ007848.1449322954/ip-172-31-14-25.eu-west-1.compute.internal
Content-Type: message/rfc822

Return-Path: <apache@ip-172-31-14-25.eu-west-1.compute.internal>
Received: from ip-172-31-14-25.eu-west-1.compute.internal (localhost [127.0.0.1])
        by ip-172-31-14-25.eu-west-1.compute.internal (8.14.4/8.14.4) with ESMTP id tB5DgXhQ007846
        for <dizzy@base5designs.co.uk>; Sat, 5 Dec 2015 13:42:33 GMT
Received: (from apache@localhost)
        by ip-172-31-14-25.eu-west-1.compute.internal (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id tB5DgX0I007845;
        Sat, 5 Dec 2015 13:42:33 GMT
To: dizzy@base5designs.co.uk
Subject: You sent a message via the ReelFilm Locations website
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 500:mail_php.php
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; charset="UTF-8"; boundary="WAMULTIBREAKWA"
From: film@reelfilmlocations.com
Reply-To: film@reelfilmlocations.com
X-Sender: film@reelfilmlocations.com
X-Priority: 3
Date: Sat, 05 Dec 2015 13:42:33 +0000 (GMT)
Message-ID: <1703740302.bdbd6db1d8cc09a957e86180fda9442a@reelfilmlocations.com>


--WAMULTIBREAKWA
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

    Message Delivered
Thank you, Dizzy High
 The following message has been sent to reelfilmlocations.
 A member of the reelfilm team will be in contact shotly.
        Message Sent    12-5-2015 | 1:42 PM

        Your Email:     dizzy@base5designs.co.uk
        Subject:        Test email from new Amazon reelfilm server
        Message:
Just a quick test to see if the contact form is working
```

From looking around i think its to do with sendmail using the headers

```
MAILER-DAEMON@ip-172-31-14-25.eu-west-1.compute.internal
```

I Really have no clue as to how to fix this, any help or advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: https://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27640 - This seems to be related (Nemesis ESMTP Service not available), the answer is to do with an SSL cert.

Comment: thanks for your reply. ssl cert is too expensive for my client and really is overkill as sensitive data is not being stored or accessed, the post also mentions Hmail server, though i'm not using any mail server except for sendmail, if that even is a mailserver

Comment: Many APIs (I can't speak for your dependencies) have a requirement that HTTPS is used to transmit info, regardless of the sensitivity of such info. Stripe, Insightly, Infusionsoft definitely do however EC2 doesn't have a minimum HTTPS requirement (according to the docs). Are you developing locally on your machine? If so, you can make a self signed SSL and attempt this again. You never know, it may work.

Comment: hey dan, the site itself is up and running currently on a 1and1 virtual server and everything functions perfectly, we have recently been receiving severe ddos attacks which 1and1 are offering no assistance hence moving to amazon, none of the code on the existing site relies on https and its not using anything special other than php and sendmail